# Pages on iOS custom paragraph styles & templates?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, pages, iwork

On Pages 1.6 for **iOS**, is there any way I can:

1. Change the paragraph styles in the document to custom ones

   i.e. The default 'blank' template has Helvetica as the body style. Can I change the body style to, say Helvetica Neue Light? Or the colour of the Title style?
2. If so, is there any way to add this template to the list of provided templates (possibly using something like iExplorer to copy it over)?

Being able to just change paragraph style is good enough, and I think it would be a bit hard to satisfy point 2, what with Apple's lock on the iOS filesystem. My current solution is to create the templates in Pages on Mac, and copy them over, then create a new document by copying from iTunes every time I need to use a custom template.

### Edit

If it's not clear from the above, I'm more interested in a solution to point 1 to point 2. It's point 1 for a reason. I already have a half solution to point 2, so I don't really need any further half-solution answers for point 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a symlink of the actual pages template directory on your Mac in your Dropbox so that you don't have to maintain two copies of your templates, and then use Dropbox to open the template files in Pages to make a new doc based on the template.

Though template files are saved as .template, Pages for iOS still opens them correctly. You can create the symlink with the following command:

```
ln -s ~/Library/Application\ Support/iWork/Pages/Templates/My\ Templates/ ~/Dropbox/Pages\ Templates
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not an ideal solution but storing the template you need in something like dropbox and then opening it from there works reasonably well for me.